# How to clear the unwanted space between the tags in this html?

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
border: 1px solid;
width: 210mm;
height: 297mm;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #333;
 }
h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
 }
h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.section {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.section h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.grid-container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
 }
.grid-item1{
    background-color: #0d315f;
    color: white;
    height: 297mm;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.grid-item2{
    color:black;
    height: 297mm;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.banner{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #1d334f;
}
.bold{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.email{
    padding:0 !important;
    margin:0 !important;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
<div class="grid-item1">
      <section class="section">
        <h1>John<br>Doe</h1><br>
        Student
        <div class="banner">Personal Info</div>
        <p class="bold">Email</p> 
        <p>yahdic@gmail.com</p>
        <p class="bold">Phone</p> 
        <p>7306219032</p>
      </section>

      <section class="section">
        <div class="banner">Skills</div>
        <ul>
          <li>CSS</li>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>PYTHON</li>
          <li>PHP</li>
          <li>C++</li>
        </ul>
      </section>

      <section class="section">
        <div class="banner">Hobbies</div>
        <ul>
          <li>Reading</li>
          <li>Watching Movies</li>
          <li>Cycling</li>
          <li>Music Listening</li>
          <li>Coding</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      
 </div>
 <div class="grid-item2">

      <section class="section">
        <h2>Education</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h3>Degree Program</h3>
            <p><strong>University Name</strong>, Location</p>
            <p><em>Date range</em></p>
            <p>GPA: X.XX/4.00</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h3>Degree Program</h3>
            <p><strong>University Name</strong>, Location</p>
            <p><em>Date range</em></p>
            <p>GPA: X.XX/4.00</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section class="section">
        <h2>Experience</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h3>Job Title</h3>
            <p><strong>Company Name</strong>, Location</p>
            <p><em>Date range</em></p>
            <ul>
              <li>Accomplishment or responsibility</li>
              <li>Accomplishment or responsibility</li>
              <li>Accomplishment or responsibility</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h3>Job Title</h3>
            <p><strong>Company Name</strong>, Location</p>
            <p><em>Date range</em></p>
            <ul>
              <li>Accomplishment or responsibility</li>
              <li>Accomplishment or responsibility</li>
              <li>Accomplishment or responsibility</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
    </div>
```

There are unwanted space between p tags like email and the actual email. the problem is not line height and i cant find where the padding/margin went wrong. Also, for the banner class (that has "personal info" and "skills", the background colour is not reaching the entire left part even though there is no margin/padding. Why?

Comment: You can use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see exactly who/where is applying CSS (including the browser's own default settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers add default margin and padding (and other properties). Usually it may be a good practice to add a style removal in your main CSS file. You may have seen CSS files with something like the following:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

In your case, after inspecting the elements, all the `p` tags have default margin on them. You can either style all of them, or create a class for the ones you want to remove. Problem with default styles is that they are browser specific, so your sites may look different on each browser if you rely on those styles.

I've added an example image of how you could've debugged it - I have selected one of the elements, went to computed and saw that it has margin (as well as it is shown on the screen). This was on Firefox.
[image]

Comment: yes it works. Thank you. Also how to make that slightly darker background of the banner "personal info" and "skills" reach to the end of the left side? currently its not starting from the leftmost place rather its starting from like a padded area. Thanks again

Comment: Same way we debugged the previous issue. You go into the HTML item inspector and start checking each element. In your case, by what I see, it's the body element having default margin again. Add margin: 0 to the independent body CSS rule. Not sure why your html, body rule is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the CSS properties you are looking for are `margin-block-start` and `margin-block-end`, they are (at least in my case (Edge Chromium)) added by the user agent.